# Excel Macro - Convert table data into date ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to show how long someone had a service based off a table with month columns and x (true) blank (false) cell entries.  For example if someone had a row of 12 "X" across the columns, the output would show them with a date range of 1/1/2023 - 12/31/2023.  If they had an "X" from column A (January) to say column J (October) their ending date range would be the last day of the previous month, so 1/1/2023 - 9/30/2023.

[image: Example Output]

I have thought about concatenating the text into a series of "x" and dashes (for blanks) and using the SUBSTITUTE function based off the concatenated output (so for example all 12 cells with "X" would be X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X) but have only gotten as far as using VBA for the concatenation.  Having trouble creating a loop macro that will take the output of the concatenation and turn it into a date range, or even if that is the right course of action.

```
Sub ConcatenateText()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ConcatenatedText As String
    
    ' Find the last row with data
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' Loop through each row start with row 2
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ConcatenatedText = ""
        ' Loop through each cell in the row
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            ' Concatenate cell value with "-"
            ConcatenatedText = ConcatenatedText & Cells(i, j).Value & "-"
        Next j
        ' Remove the trailing "-"
        Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Value = Left(ConcatenatedText, Len(ConcatenatedText) - 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This should be doable with a formula, no VBA needed.

Comment: The result on col M doesn't follow the the logic `last day of the previous month`. Which one is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

As a User Defined Function

```vb
Option Explicit

Function XtoDate(rng As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long, m As Long, dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date
    For i = 1 To rng.Count
        If UCase(rng(i)) = "X" Then
            If dt1 = 0 Then
               dt1 = DateSerial(Year(Date), i, 1)
            End If
            m = m + 1
        End If
    Next
    dt2 = DateAdd("M", m, dt1) - 1
    XtoDate = Format(dt1, "m/d/yyyy") & _
        "-" & Format(dt2, "m/d/yyyy")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If a formula is acceptable place this in M2 array formula and drag down.

```
=TEXT(DATE(2023,MIN(IF(A2:L2="x",1,100)*COLUMN(A:L)),1),"yyyy/mm/dd")&"-"&TEXT(DATE(2023,MAX(IF(A2:L2="x",1,0)*COLUMN(A:L))+1,1)-1,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Adjust date format as required.

Answer (score 0):

The result on `column M` on OP's screenshot does not follow the logic `last day of the previous month`.

Both logic are provide as options in below code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sStart As String, sEnd As String
    Dim arrData, arrRes(), rngData As Range
    Const iYr As Integer = 2023
    arrData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 0)
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sStart = "": sEnd = ""
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            If LCase(arrData(i, j)) = "x" Then
                If Len(sStart) = 0 Then sStart = Format(DateSerial(iYr, j, 1), "m/d/yyyy")
                ' Option1: End day = "last day of the previous month"
'                sEnd = Format(DateSerial(iYr, j, IIf(j = 12 Or j = 1, 31, -1)), "m/d/yyyy")
                ' Option2: End day logic is same as OP's screenshot
                sEnd = Format(DateSerial(iYr, j + 1, 0), "m/d/yyyy")
            End If
        Next j
        arrRes(i, 0) = sStart & "-" & sEnd
    Next i
    Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(arrData), 1).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]